# Creating Static Persistent Volume in AKS using credentials in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-aks, azure-keyvault, persistent-volumes, azure-file-share

I am currently following this guide here to create a PV using an existing Azure File Share: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume

The method is to store the storage account name and access key in a secret `azure secret` then use it in the csi section of the yaml file as below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: azurefile
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: azurefile-csi
  csi:
    driver: file.csi.azure.com
    readOnly: false
    volumeHandle: unique-volumeid  # make sure this volumeid is unique in the cluster
    volumeAttributes:
      resourceGroup: EXISTING_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME  # optional, only set this when storage account is not in the same resource group as agent node
      shareName: aksshare
    nodeStageSecretRef:
      name: azure-secret
      namespace: default
  mountOptions:
    - dir_mode=0777
    - file_mode=0777
    - uid=0
    - gid=0
    - mfsymlinks
    - cache=strict
    - nosharesock
    - nobrl
```

However, due to technical risk and security reasons, now I do not want to put storage account access key in the kubernetes namespace. Instead, I want to fetch the access key from Azure key vault and use it to mount the persistent volume to the azure files.

I have done some research and testing, but to no avail. Would appreciate help on this, thanks!

Comment: Running into the same problem - how did you solve it in the end?

Answer (score -1):

***We can fetch the access key from keyvault to mount the persistent volume to fileshare using providerClass instead of storage account access key***

***I have created RG and AKS Cluster***

*While creating the AKS Cluster we have to enable the CSI Drivers*

[image]

***I have created the keyvault to secure our secrets***
*Resources>Keyvault>Create>RG,kvName>Review&Create*

[image]

***I have created the secrets using keyvaults***

*In KV Go-To secrets>click on Generate/import >give the name and secret value to create the secrets and its value(password)*

[image]

***Verify that your virtual machine scale set have their own system-assigned identity, if not we have to enable it***

[image]

***I have given the Access policy permissions to read the keyvault and its content***

Go-To>keyvault>access-policy>create>

- Permissions>select>secret Permissions
- principal>select>id
- application>select application id>create

[image]

[image]

***Created the secretprovider class by using this provider class by this class will get the secrets from the key vault***

[secretproviderclass(check the file here)](https://github.com/komali323/yaml-files.git)

***Apply the below command to deploy the secret class***

```
       kubectl apply -f filename.yaml
```

***By deploying the provider class the secrets will not be created, for that we have to create the POD which will mount the volume by utilizing the CSI drivers***

[pod.yaml(check this link)](https://github.com/komali323/yaml-files.git)

***Deploy the pod using below command***

```
  kubectl apply -f file.yaml
```

[image]

***After the pod starts, the mounted content at the volume path that we specified in YAML file will be available***

```
kubectl exec <pod_name> -- ls /mnt/secrets-store/       
kubectl exec <pod_name> -- cat /mnt/secrets-store/<secret_name>
```

***By using the above commands we will get the secret and secret value.***

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but my problem is how to use secret for PV, not pod